# Regex to match two consecutive characters unless followed/preceded by more of the same character

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like this: `qqq Eqq Eqqq Cqq Eqq Fq`. I want to replace all sequences where there are two consecutive characters (in this case `qq`) with an `h`, with the desired output looking like this: `qqq Eh Eqqq Ch Eh Fq`

However, I do not want the regex to match sequences of more than two q's (`qqq` or `qqqq`) and make the string look like this: `hq Eh Ehq Ch Eh Fq`. I've tried the below but that results in the output I don't want.

```
text = "qqq Eqq Eqqq Cqq Eqq Fq";
text = text.replaceAll("[q]{2}", "h");
```

I've also tried only replacing `q`'s followed by a whitespace character but this just ends up matching the last two `q`'s in each word. Is there a way to replace two consecutive characters unless they are followed by a third or fourth of that same character? The language is Java if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a lookaround based regex:

```
String text = "qqq Eqq Eqqq Cqq Eqq Fq";
text = text.replaceAll("(?<!q)q{2}", "h");
System.out.println(text);
// => hq Eh Ehq Ch Eh Fq
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/YXm8gf) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/okCrab/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!q)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `q` immediately to the left of the current location
- `q{2}` - 2 `q` chars.

Note: if you plan to only replace 2 `q` chars not surrounded with `q`s, add a negative lookahead `(?!q)` at the end, `"(?<!q)q{2}(?!q)"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match any character, not a specific one, you have to use something quite convoluted as Java's regex doesn't support `variable-length look-behind`s. I came up with this:

```
(?!([a-z])\1\1)(.)([a-z])\3(?!\3)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?!            # negative look-ahead
  ([a-z])\1\1  # [group 1] match a letter and 2 more of the same letter
)              # end of the negative look-ahead
(.)            # [group 2] match any character - this is for some other character 
               # before what you want ('E', 'C', or 'F' in your examples)
               # this will not match the repeated character -
               # guaranteed by the previous negative look-ahead
([a-z])        # [group 3] the letter to be replaced
\3             # the same letter (reference to the previous group)
(?!\3)         # negative look-ahead - 
               # makes the pattern not match more than 2 of the same character
```

You have to replace with `$2h` (`$2` is `(.)` in the pattern)

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/fPImpr), [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/okCrab/2)